# Updating a Launch file to look at a Publisher

Tags: ros, roslaunch, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get Lidar (Neato) and mapping (Hector) working together, this has been done here
https://github.com/njzhangyifei/xv11-hector-slam-roslaunch

I have got this working but the launch file looks directly at the USB port (https://github.com/njzhangyifei/xv11-hector-slam-roslaunch/blob/master/hector_neato.launch)

```
<node pkg="xv_11_laser_driver" type="neato_laser_publisher" name="xv_11_node">
    <!--<param name="port" value="/dev/tty.usbserial-A9UXLBBR"/>-->
    <param name="port" value="/dev/tty.LIDAR-DevB"/>
    <param name="firmware_version" value="2"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="laser"/>
  </node>
```

However I now have my **Lidar working on my robot** and running ROS (RVIZ) on my Desktop and so the port is on a different machine (ROS_MASTER_URI is all setup)

How do I update the Launch file to look at the remote robot for the Lidar Node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251271/updating-a-launch-file-to-look-at-a-publisher/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The neato_laser_publisher node needs to run on the robot controller, not your desktop, precisely so that it can access the device hardware.

In practice, I've found that it's best to have essentially all nodes running on the robot controller, and only run rviz and other diagnostic tools on your desktop. This will minimize network traffic and make your robot more resilient to networking problems.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-05**:
Yes thats what I thought but how can I update the Launch file to point at the Lidar node on the robot instead  of the settings listed

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-01-05**:
Comment out line 11 (https://github.com/njzhangyifei/xv11-hector-slam-roslaunch/blob/master/hector_neato.launch#L11), then roslaunch this file on the robot. On the desktop, run this: "rosrun rviz rviz -d rviz_cfg.rviz".